# serial byte check within timeout (asm)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, quickbasic

I'm interfacing with hardware through the RS232 serial port. This time with wireless modules. I decided to use DOS as my OS over anything else because its real-time (which means no process can interrupt the operation of the serial port).

I created a critical section in which a specific character has to be received by a certain time in QuickBasic but I want to port this section to assembly (machine code) so I don't have to wait extra microseconds for QuickBasic internal processing.

This is my QuickBasic code:

```
start# = TIMER
DO
IF (TIMER-start#) > .1# THEN
PRINT "failure"
END
END IF
LOOP UNTIL INP(&H3F8) = &H5A
PRINT "SUCCESS"
```

Now I want to port this into an assembly fragment I can apply a call absolute command to in QuickBasic, except I don't know if the code I'm using will work. (is my use of the si register acceptable here?). I want the assembly code to return a 1 if there's a timeout or a 0 if the correct character is received on the serial line.

So far, I came up with the following code (based on help from Ralf Brown's Interrupt List):

```
push bp    'save pointer
mov bp,sp  'get copy
mov ah,00
int 1A     'get bios time
mov si,cx
mainloop:
    mov ah,00
    int 1A  
    mov ax,cx
    sub ax,si
    sub ax,03 'use a 3 tick timeout
    jc timeout
    mov dx,03F8
    in dx,al
    cmp al,5A
    jne notfound
      mov ax,0 'return 0 for got character
      jmp ending
    notfound:
jmp mainloop
timeout:
mov ax,1 'return 1 for timeout
ending:
mov bx,[bp+06]
mov [bx],ax
pop bp
retf 2
```

Am I nailing this? or do I need to make changes?

Comment: Most assemblers will need `1Ah` to interpret `1A` as a hex number instead of a syntax error.  But I guess I'm not familiar with whatever you're using because it also apparently uses `'` as the comment character.

Comment: `... no process can interrupt ... ` - Timer0 uses INT 08H, and by default is triggered every 54.925 ms ~= 18.2 hz. It usually calls INT 1CH, For real time code, you may want to save and replace the pointer for INT 08H to point to your own function to reduce the overhead (or shut off timer interrupts). I think this is used to update time of day, so you may need a way to restore the time of day if you effectively disable the timer0 stuff (perhaps the real time clock (or the equivalent)).

Comment: Anyway, QuickBasic uses DOS's Pascal calling convention. Left to right arguments on the stack, return values in DX:AX (or just AX). All calls in Quickbasic are FAR so you need the `retf` and the caller cleans up the stack. **Important:** It also requires that _SI, DI, BP_, or _DS_ registers be saved and restored IF they are changed. Your code changes _BP_ and _SI_ although _BP_ is already being saved and restored.  After `mov bp, sp` do a `push si` and before the `pop bp` do a `pop si`

Comment: Is it my imagination or is your Bsic code trying for a .1 second timeout and your assembly code is almost .2 seconds. The assembly code waits until the Carry Flag (borrow) is set which happens when the interval goes from 3 to -1 which could be as much as 4*.055 seconds. Of course the timer is only accurate to (~55ms=1/18.2). What is the timeout value you are trying to achieve? The method you use in assembly requires interrupts to be on. You could use the 8253 (PIT) to set a count down timer and poll it until the countdown timer expires. You could do that with interrupts off.

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: I'm just using dos debug to help me get the machine codes for the assembly code. What I am effectively trying to do is read a character from the serial port within the time its supposed to arrive (so for example, 260uS for a character at 38kbps). Maybe I won't be able to get that low but with QuickBasic alone, I think the finest precision is 10mS which is super high because my hardware expects to receive a packet of up to 30 bytes within a 30mS timeframe but I'd rather have it receive those bytes within 20mS.